# shellscript in C: using awk getting runaway string constant error

Tags: c, linux, bash, awk

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
awk 'BEGIN { FS=\":\"; print \"User\t\tUID\n--------------------\"; } { print $1,\"\t\t\",$3;} END { print \"--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!\" }' /etc/passwd \n\
    "

void displayusers()
{
    system(SHELLSCRIPT);
}
```

**The error message is:**

```
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "User...
```

**The bash cmd when run and works in the terminal is:**

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; print "User\t\tUID\n--------------------"; } { print $1,"\t\t",$3;} END { print "--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!" }' /etc/passwd
```

I think somewhere when using `\` to block out the various `"` for c it messed up my awk. But I'm not sure where. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply took your string and used it in a `printf()` statement, and then analyzed the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
awk 'BEGIN { FS=\":\"; print \"User\t\tUID\n--------------------\"; } { print $1,\"\t\t\",$3;} END { print \"--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!\" }' /etc/passwd \n\
    "

int main(void)
{
    printf("[[%s]]\n", SHELLSCRIPT);
    return 0;

}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./runaway
[[#/bin/bash 
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; print "User        UID
--------------------"; } { print $1,"       ",$3;} END { print "--------------------
All Users and UIDs Printed!" }' /etc/passwd 
    ]]
$
```

When I made the line ends visible (`^J` marks the end of line, `^I` tabs), the problem is transparent:

```
[[#/bin/bash ^J
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; print "User^I^IUID^J
--------------------"; } { print $1,"^I^I",$3;} END { print "--------------------^J
All Users and UIDs Printed!" }' /etc/passwd ^J
    ]]^J
```

You have two occurrences of `\n` in the string which need to be `\\n`.  It is up to you whether you change the appearances of `\t` to `\\t`; it works either way.

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash\n\
awk 'BEGIN { FS=\":\"; print \"User\t\tUID\\n--------------------\"; } { print $1,\"\t\t\",$3;} END { print \"--------------------\\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!\" }' /etc/passwd\n"
```

Using that in my program yields:

```
[[#/bin/bash^J
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; print "User^I^IUID\n--------------------"; } { print $1,"^I^I",$3;} END { print "--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!" }' /etc/passwd^J
]]^J
```

Note, in particular, the technique used to debug this.  Print the data so you can see it precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but here's a useful-looking article [just about this topic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) and it would appear that your choices are something along the following lines:

- if you have different quotes surrounding the text, you don't need to escape the interior ones
- you can use the same quotes surrounding and escape the interior ones
- you can use octal sequences for the quotes, e.g. <\42>
- if it get's too confusing, move the string into a separate file where quoting will not be an issue